# "Take THE torch" or "Take A torch"?

Tags: articles

Is it OK to say "Take the torch" if the word "torch" is mentioned in the sentence for the first time.
The full sentence is "Take the/a torch to light up your way"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes

> Take the torch to light up your way.

is perfectly acceptable. It implies that there is a specific torch being refereed to. This might be mentioned later, or implied by context. This usage would be particularly common when "the torch" is metaphorical, and stands for "reason" or "justice" or some such abstract attribute. If any torch in general is meant, then "a torch"  would be the usual form, although some speakers are careless about this distinction.